# how to maintain the width of drop down list?

Tags: asp.net

I have used two drop down lists.

1. The 1st drop down list contains 2 values
2. the 2nd drop down list contains 3 values.

When I select the `1st value` of the 1st `dropdownlist` the 2nd `dropdownlist` gets `disabled`.

But the problem is, at the time of getting disabled the width of the disabled `dropdownlost` increases and I do not want that.

Can any one please help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asp.net Page:**

```
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:30%; text-align:right;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDropDownlist1" runat="server">Drop Down List 1</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%; text-align:left;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="width:30%; text-align:right;">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblDropDownlist2" runat="server">Drop Down List 2</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%; text-align:left;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="100%">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**Code behind in C#**

```
public partial class DropDownlist : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            try
            {
                if (ddl1.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                    ddl2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddl2.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               string b=  ex.Message;
            }

    }
}
```

**Code behind file in VB.net**

```
Protected Sub ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddl1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            If ddl1.SelectedValue = "1" Then
                ddl2.Enabled = False
            Else
                ddl2.Enabled = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

This works fine..!!

Hope this helps

Happy Coding

Comment: fantastic... there is other way how i solved it.  I just explicitly set the width of the drop down list to 90px. and its working all fantastic